# Delay a submenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay

I have make a script. That open my submenu in the navigation. When you go mouse out of the submenu. The submenu must be closed with a delay of 300ms. But the delay is not working. How can i fix this? This is my script:

```
$('.nav-main .container li').hover(function() {
    if ($(this).find('.submenu').length > 0) {
        $(this).addClass("hover");
        $(this).find('.submenu').show();
    }
}, function() {
    $(this).find('.submenu').delay(300).hide();
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
});
```

Comment: [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested the following code but it should work ...

```
$('.nav-main .container li').hover(function() {
    if ($(this).find('.submenu').length > 0) {
        $(this).addClass("hover");
        $(this).find('.submenu').show();
    }
}, function() {
    var submenu = $(this).find('.submenu');
    setTimeout(function() {
      submenu.hide();
    }, 300);
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a setTimeout() method, also, you need to define an object to be used inside of your function $(this) will be null.

```
$('.nav-main .container li').hover(function() {
    if ($(this).find('.submenu').length > 0) {
        $(this).addClass("hover");
        $(this).find('.submenu').show();
    }
}, function() {
    var object = $(this);
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        $(object).find('.submenu').hide();
        $(object).removeClass("hover");
    }, 300);
});
```